# AlloyUI with ASP.net MVC Anyone?

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-mvc, yui, alloy-ui

Has anyone used AlloyUI with ASP.net MVC 4.0 ? Found this UI library very useful.

I'm planning to use it in an enterprise class application.

Though the library looks great, I'm not finding any resources except for their official API. Neither does the Nuget gallery have the library for download.

Will there be any compatibility issues with jQuery/KnockoutJS or MVC 4?

Comment: AlloyUI is built on top of YUI, so if you need documentation on the base YUI components it's built on top of, you can check out http://yuilibrary.com/

Answer (score 1):

AlloyUI is perfect for enterprise class applications. It's the official UI framework of Liferay, which is the leading open source portal solution for enterprise with more than 500,000 worldwide deployments.

There are no compatibilities issues with any kind of framework (front-end or back-end).

Comment: Perfect for enterprise apps, but lacks some quite important features, like a good data grid implementation with sorting/paging/filtering.

Answer (score 0):

I have used YUI3 in two projects with ASP.net MVC 4.0. One of these is http://triumftaxi.com/en to order taxi online. There is demo.

Since the project uses Backbone and their JS components required jQuery, for a short time both libraries lived together. There were no issues.

Since AlloyUI is built on top of YUI3, everything written above matches to AlloyUI too - you won't have issues.

Hope that helps!